# Apply different css stylesheet for different parts of the same web page

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have a web page with different parts which require different css stylesheets to be applied to each. What I would like to know is how to specify which css stylesheet to use for each different part of the web page. if I leave them all together, the components do not get displayed properly.

Comment: What the user means is that he has multiple **.css files being called into one web page but that page is not displaying correctly because of (obvious) conflicts.  I guess the css files have divs / sections with the same names which is causing the conflict.  That is what is he asking and the answer below by Ned seems to be an excellent answer.

Comment: It is obvious what this question is asking, so it seems clear to me that it is a 'real question'.

Comment: This question is clear and makes sense to me. I despise when the moderators close questions on here.

Comment: For example, take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/

Comment: Exactly this is about "css scope" the current css implementation does not allow to implement style-independent MVC modules. Still valid in 2016.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't apply different stylesheets to different parts of a page.  You have a few options:

The best is to wrap the different parts of the page in divs with class names:

```
<div class='part1'>
    ....
</div>

<div class='part2'>
    ....
</div>
```

Then in your part1 CSS, prefix every CSS rule with ".part1 " and in your part2 CSS, prefix every CSS rule with ".part2 ".  Note that by using classes, you can use a number of different "part1" or "part2" divs, to flexibly delimit which parts of the page are affected by which CSS rules.

Comment: 6 years later... :( there is still no scoped css.
Why browsers still do not support this feature?

Answer (score 6):

It is called **Cascading** Style Sheets  (CSS) for a reason ..

use the [specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) rules of CSS to target each section..

ie..

```
#section1 a{color:red}
#section2 a{color:blue}
```

this will make all links inside an element with id `section1` be red, and all links inside an element with id `section2` be blue..

```
<div id="section1">
 <a href="#">i will be red</a>
</div>
<div id="section2">
 <a href="#">i will be blue</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That does not do help when loading bootstrap.css or any other external css

Comment: Having to post here due to the question closure, which I also feel is in error. In my case I have conflicts between CSS libraries in different parts of a page (an angular ui embedded within a bootstrap based admin ui from django). The approach I'm about to try is embedding one in an iframe.

Comment: Newer versions of bootstrap provide .less or .scss format, which can be easily wrapped by your custom wrapper to achieve scoping. like:
#section1 {
}

Answer (score 1):

An external stylesheet is applied to whole html page.
In order to apply different stylesheets to different portions,
**Firstly,** the html page has to be divided into different sections using the html  tag ( with each html div to be assigned a unique id or class)
**Secondly,** the external stylesheet to be applied to each div has to be designed according to the id/class assigned to it

Example as explained above by Gaby aka G. Petrioli...

Answer (score 0):

Use different class for each part in your web page and customize the CSS code for each class.