# Different css for different pages

Tags: css

I have a blog on Blogger and have some widgets. I was wondering that is it possible that a widget is displayed differently on a homepage as compared to rest of the pages?

For example a box

```
/* on home page, it should appear like this */
#box {
background: green;
width:200px; height:100px;
}

/* on other pages, it should appear like this */
#box {
background: red;
width:200px; height:200px;
}
```

Comment: default wordpress add class in your body. if you access on home page added home class and other page to page class added by wordpress theme. use .home #box{} for home page other page for .page #box{}.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest, put an ID into your home page like,

`<body id="home">` and other ids for other pages

Now the CSS changes would be

```
/* on home page, it should appear like this */
#home #box {
background: green;
width:200px; height:100px;
}

/* on other pages, it should appear like this */
#others #box {
background: red;
width:200px; height:200px;
}
```

Comment: I have already mentioned that I am on blogger. When I looked up my template, there is only one body element. How can I create different body elements for different pages and posts.

Answer (score 1):

give the body a id

```
<body id="page">
```

then you can identify it with

```
#page #box { 
    .... your CODE
}
```

I guarantee this will work :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to put this code htlm code page not css code page if you said !important it is override other code

```
      <style>
             #box {
              background: red !important;
    width:200px !important; 
height:200px !important;
    }    
        </style>
```

Comment: This is invalid syntax.

Comment: Better, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: ı have same problem last months. Are you sure you put this code at your html page at part of css import? becase it work at me :( update it ı am again

Comment: Read the question again; it isn't asking how to make a box red, but rather how to have css affect items differently, on different pages.

Comment: ı read question body =) ı write my html code with notepad++ may be your ide is different becase ı was used carusel its height and width is different all of my page.. have a good day

Comment: I'm not using an IDE; I can tell just by looking at what you have given that it doesn't answer the question.  This makes a div with an id of 'box' red.. it doesn't depend upon the page that is being served.  In fact, all you did is copy the OP's code an add `!important` to it.

Comment: dont understand me wrong ı want to ask for learing..as you said my code come red.. if you put this code your between html codes  and said important to it will be red.. background: red !important; this mean dont read other background clour read only this code

Comment: And that isn't the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply different stylesheets to different parts of a page. You have a few options:

The best is to wrap the different parts of the page in divs with class names:
[REFER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298746/apply-different-css-stylesheet-for-different-parts-of-the-same-web-page)

```
  <div class='part1'>
    ....
</div>

<div class='part2'>
    ....
</div>
```

Then in your part1 CSS, prefix every CSS rule with ".part1 " and in your part2 CSS, prefix every CSS rule with ".part2 ". Note that by using classes, you can use a number of different "part1" or "part2" divs, to flexibly delimit which parts of the page are affected by which CSS rules.