# my inline CSS under a box (segment) of my webpage is affecting other parts of the same page

Tags: html, css

I am using this software (Swiiit Website Builder) purchased by my company, im doing intranet page for my department (im a total learn on the job dude being tasked to do this) please help!

```
<style><!--
<html>
<head>
<style>

ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    float: center;
    width: 6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000080;
    padding: 0.6em 4.5em;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: #0000cd;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
--></style>
```

the style will affect other area of the page; how do i edit it?

i tried to understand this [Apply different css stylesheet for different parts of the same web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298746/apply-different-css-stylesheet-for-different-parts-of-the-same-web-page) but im still cracking my head...

I have amended according to the recommendation (see below) and **turn out great!!! Thanks!!**
doesnt affect other parts of page now, but now the space between blocks of links are so wide apart when i launch the code... looks fine in preview mode though... please assist :)

```
.something ul { 
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0; 
list-style-type: none; 

}

.something li {
    display: inline;
}

.something a {
    float: center;
    width: 6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: #000080;
    padding: 0.6em 4.5em;
    border-right: 1px solid green;
}

.something a:hover {
    background-color: #0000cd;
}

<div class="something">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Organisation</a></li>
<li><a href="#">XXX</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Organisational Chart</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<p><img style="display: block; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;" src="/wbn/slot/u3733/Org%20Chart.png" alt="" width="800" height="473" /></p>
```

Comment: share your html also

Comment: What are the `<style><!--` and `--></style>` tags doing at the start and end of your snippet?

Comment: i have the <html> and <head> and <style> at the beginning of the code, but the software auto removed it and replaced with <style><!-->

Comment: <p><img style="display: block; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;" src="/wbn/slot/u3733/Org%20Chart.png" alt="" width="800" height="473" /></p>

Comment: thats my html after the css code above

Answer (score 1):

Set class for every `ul`, `a` and `li` otherwise

```
<div class="something">
<ul>
<li>....</li>
<li>....</li>
</ul>
<a href="">...</a>
</div>
```

Give styles using the class name like,

```
.something ul { }
.something li { }
.something a { }
```

Comment: awesome thank as mentioned above... right now there is this issue of white space between the blocks... i understand that i could deploy the method mentioned in [link]http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/[link] (adjust html or css) which one would be better in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Set specific class or id to the elements like

```
<a href=" " id="a">text</a>
```

You can style this a in your css by

```
#a{
style
}
```

Comment: when you said style a in my css, do you mean style it in my css sheet? or within the html coding area?

Comment: @yennie You can do it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding styling to your *elements*, add them to a `class` or `id`

**class definition:**

*html*

```
<div class="myClassIsReusableToAllWithThisClass"></div>
```

*css*

```
.myClassIsReusableToAllWithThisClass{
/*add styling to all which have a class called 'myClassIsReusableToAllWithThisClass'*/
}
```

---

**ID definition:**

*html*

```
<div id="uniqueID"></div>
```

*css*

```
#uniqueID{
 /*add styling to only one element*/
}
```

---

**element definition:** (what you're doing presently)

*html*

```
<div></div>
```

*css*

```
div{
 /*add styling to all 'div' elements*/
}
```

---

As @James Donnelly has already mentioned, you should also remove these:

```
<!--   and -->
```

as these are 'comments' in html, and will render all within them void/ go unnoticed by your browser.

## DEMO:

```css
#myID {
  color: red;
}
.myClass {
  background: blue;
}
a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div >I'm just a div</div>
<br/>

<div id="myID">I have a specific id</div>
<br/>
<div class="myClass">I have a specific class which is reusable to all with this class</div>
<br/>


<div class="myClass">I have the myClass class</div>
<br/>

<a>I'm an a tag with no class or id. But all 'a' tags will have this styling</a>
```

Comment: for the <!--   and -->, i deleted them, closed and saved. then open to check... this stupid programme added it back again...

Comment: @yennie: does that first style tag have a closing tag? since that very first style tag could be removed completely.