# Injected html inherits css from websites

Tags: html, css

Is there any possible way to make injected html use only my own written css without making all lines `!important`? because some html parts inherit style from existing website css file.

Comment: If your question is "can I apply different CSS to different parts of the page, the answer is 'no' (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298746/apply-different-css-stylesheet-for-different-parts-of-the-same-web-page)), you must use specificity rules (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25105841/4682556)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using more specificity to add weight to the CSS you are declaring. For example, if your injected HTML has a class for the first parent it could be: `.injected .things`. Do note that ID's have more weight over class. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

Keep your (css file) at the bottom of all other (css files)

in this case you don't need to put important in your style.css file

like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Index</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Please see attached image:
[image]